# Map control: Remove or hide default map layer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 application I'm using a custom `TileSource` in order to overlap the default map background with a custom tile, in this way:

C#:

```
public class CustomTileSource : TileSource
{
   public CustomTileSource()
   {
      UriFormat ="http://myurl/{0}/{1}/{2}.png";
   }

   public override Uri GetUri(int x, int y, int zoomLevel)
   {

      if (zoomLevel > 0 && zoomLevel <= 18)
      {
          var url = string.Format(UriFormat, zoomLevel, x, y);
          return new Uri(url);
       }
       //if zoom level is not supported, return null
        return null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
...
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
xmlns:tileSource="clr-namespace:Mappa"
...

<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
   <maps:Map x:Name="Map" Center="45,9" ZoomLevel="14">
      <maps:Map.TileSources>
         <tileSource:CustomTileSource />
      </maps:Map.TileSources>
    </maps:Map>
</Grid>
```

My problem is that I need to remove the default map layer in order to hide labels (underground stations, neighborhood names, etc).

I know this could be done quite easily with Windows Phone 8.1 with the `MapTileLayer.BackgroundReplacement` property (as state [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn632728.aspx#replacing_the_default_map)) but I cannot find any information about Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this myself with the new WP8 "Nokia HERE maps" map control but was unable to achieve this. I had to resort to falling back to the older "Bing" based map control in Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps (marked as obsolete).

Here's how to remove the other layers in the older Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps control:

```
for (var i = Map.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    MapTileLayer tileLayer = Map.Children[i] as MapTileLayer;
    if (tileLayer != null)
    {
        Map.Children.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Even though this older map control has been superseded in WP8 the newer control doesn't seem to support the same flexibility with layers and the "obsolete" control still works happily under WP8.1 if used in your app.

Here's my app which still uses the older control which is probably achieving what you're trying to do - [NZ Topo Map app for Windows Phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-nz/store/app/nz-topo-map/b861ab51-a68d-456f-9ae4-cbed66736b36).